# How to use boost::serialization with nested structs and minimal code changes?

Tags: c++, boost

Currently we use POD which is stored in nested structs. Example:

```
#define MaxNum1 100;
#define MaxNum2 50;

struct A
{
    int Value[MaxNum1]; 
    char SomeChar = 'a';
};

struct B
{
    A data[MaxNum2];
    float SomeFloat = 0.1f;
};


int main()
{
    B StructBObject = {};
}
```

We want to enhance our data structures using std::vector just like this:

```
struct NewA
{
    std::vector<int> Value; 
    char SomeChar = 'a';
};

struct NewB
{
    std::vector<NewA> data;
    float SomeFloat = 0.1f;
};

int main()
{
    NewB StructNewBObject = {};
}
```

The only argument against this modification is that `NewA` and `NewB` are no POD anymore and this makes reading/writing to a file more complicated.

How is it possible to read/write `NewA` and `NewB` to a file using `boost::serialization` with minimal
code changes to `NewA` and `NewB`? Minimal code changes are important because we use for example big structs which have up to 7 nested levels.

Comment: why do you consider moving from `int Value[100];` to `std::vector` an enhanchment? Dont get me wrong, I am among the biggest fanboys of `std::vector`, but a vector is not a fixed sized array. The exact replacement would rather be a `std::array<int,100>`, or just staying with the c-array isnt that bad either when the size is fixed

Comment: also see here for PODness of `std::array` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674247/is-stdarrayt-s-guaranteed-to-be-pod-if-t-is-pod

Comment: @ idclev 463035818: I consider moving to std::vector as an enhancement because often our c-arrays in the structs are not realy of fixed size. Sometimes we use an extra integer to store the number of the maximal element.

Comment: ok, then it seems like `std::array` is not an option

Comment: Could you give out an example on how you use `boost::serialization` with the `A` and `B` structures? From my attempts, I seem to only get it to work if I create a templated serialize method, for which it makes no difference if it's an array or a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can serialize using boost serialization¹:

```
template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, A& a, unsigned) {
    ar & a.Value & a.SomeChar;
}
template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, B& b, unsigned) {
    ar & b.data & b.SomeFloat;
}
```

Using these, you will *already* have the correct behaviour out of the box with both the C-array and std::vector approaches.

If you want to keep using fixed-size trivially-copyable types², you can use something like Boost Container's `static_vector`: it will keep track of the current size, but the data is statically allocated right inside the structures.

### TRIPLE DEMO

Here's a triple demo program with three implementations depending on the `IMPL` variable.

As you can see the bulk of the code is kept invariant. However, for "best comparison" I've made sure that all the containers are at half capacity (50/25) before serialization.

The main program also deserializes.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c7d57a4a6d56d64)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/is_bitwise_serializable.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>

#include <iostream>

#if (IMPL==0) // C arrays
    struct A {
        int Value[100]; 
        char SomeChar = 'a';
    };

    struct B {
        A data[50];
        float SomeFloat = 0.1f;
    };

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, A& a, unsigned) {
        ar & a.Value & a.SomeChar;
    }
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, B& b, unsigned) {
        ar & b.data & b.SomeFloat;
    }

#elif (IMPL==1) // std::vector
    #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
    struct A {
        std::vector<int> Value;
        char SomeChar = 'a';
    };

    struct B {
        std::vector<A> data;
        float SomeFloat = 0.1f;
    };

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, A& a, unsigned) {
        ar & a.Value & a.SomeChar;
    }
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, B& b, unsigned) {
        ar & b.data & b.SomeFloat;
    }

#elif (IMPL==2) // static_vector
    #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
    #include <boost/container/static_vector.hpp>
    struct A {
        boost::container::static_vector<int, 100> Value; 
        char SomeChar = 'a';
    };

    struct B {
        boost::container::static_vector<A, 50> data; 
        float SomeFloat = 0.1f;
    };

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, A& a, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_array(a.Value.data(), a.Value.size()) & a.SomeChar;
    }
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, B& b, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_array(b.data.data(), b.data.size()) & b.SomeFloat;
    }

#endif

namespace bio = boost::iostreams;
static constexpr auto flags = boost::archive::archive_flags::no_header;
using BinaryData = std::vector</*unsigned*/ char>;

int main() {
    char const* impls[] = {"C style arrays", "std::vector", "static_vector"};
    std::cout << "Using " << impls[IMPL] << " implementation: ";
    BinaryData serialized_data;

    {
        B object = {};
#if IMPL>0
        {
            // makes sure all containers half-full
            A element;
            element.Value.resize(50);
            object.data.assign(25, element);
        }
#endif

        bio::stream<bio::back_insert_device<BinaryData>> os { serialized_data };
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(os, flags);

        oa << object;
    }

    std::cout << "Size: " << serialized_data.size() << "\n";

    {
        bio::array_source as { serialized_data.data(), serialized_data.size() };
        bio::stream<bio::array_source> os { as };
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(os, flags);

        B object;
        ia >> object;
    }
}
```

Printing

```
Using C style arrays implementation: Size: 20472
Using std::vector implementation: Size: 5256
Using static_vector implementation: Size: 5039
```

## Final Thoughts

See also:

- [Boost serialization bitwise serializability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121545/boost-serialization-bitwise-serializability)
- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#binaryobjects

---

¹ (but keep in mind portability, as you probably already are aware with the POD approach, see [C++ Boost::serialization : How do I archive an object in one program and restore it in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073936/c-boostserialization-how-do-i-archive-an-object-in-one-program-and-restore/27075717#27075717))

² not POD, as with the NSMI your types weren't POD

Comment: Love your answers because I already know who wrote it before I get to the end, based only on its wonderful presentation.

Comment: Thank you, @GManNickG That makes my day